# Eclipse CDT and OpenCV issue

Tags: c++, opencv, eclipse-cdt

I'm trying to make OpenCV work in Eclipse CDT, provided that I'm using the following under `Windows 7`:

I have set the path for `Includes` under `Cygwin C++ Compiler` as follows: `C:\OpenCV2.2\include\opencv`

And, also set the path for `Libraries` under `Cygwin Linker` as follows: `C:\OpenCV2.2\lib`

When I try to build the project, I get the following two errors:

`cannot find -lC:/OpenCV2.2/lib`

`make: *** [OpenCVDemo.exe] Error 1`

Any ideas why am I getting that?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You need to add `C:\OpenCV2.2\lib` as a **library path**, not a library. Add libraries that you will use:

```
opencv_core
opencv_highgui
```

etc.

Also you may need to use include directory `C:\OpenCV2.2\include\opencv2` and `#include <opencv.hpp>`.